# How to write SQL++ Couchbase query which returns total count and paged data?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a below query

```
SELECT count_data.count, paged_data.* FROM
(
  (SELECT count(*) as count FROM main_data) AS count_data,
  (SELECT hosp_d.* FROM main_data AS hosp_d LIMIT 5) AS paged_data
)
```

My expected output json is like below

```
{
  "count" : 5,
  "paged_data" : [{...},{...}]
}
```

Comment: Did this query not work? What went wrong?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, the issue is count is being copied to every output row, making it part of data model (paged_data) itself, we do not want our java model entity at backend have count or total in it.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any way to get around that, without splitting into two queries. One possible workaround would be the create a model that inherits from the entity model, but adds a 'count' field, and then you could grab that count from the first one, and then return the collection of models recast as the base class. I'm not sure this is the best approach, but I know it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option, using a CTE. This approach might not be as performant, because ALL the results are in the CTE, and then LIMIT/OFFSET is applied in the SELECT. I'd definitely benchmark and measure to make sure the performance is okay, but this approach will get your results close to the form you want:

```
WITH articlesData AS (
  SELECT
     field1,
     field2,
     COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalCount
  FROM <collection>
  JOIN <whatever>
  WHERE <predicates>
)
SELECT VALUE { 
  "count": articlesData[0].articlesCount,
  "paged_list" : (SELECT x.* FROM articlesData x LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0)}
```

Comment: thanks Matthew, this works but performance is something i am not sure of.

Comment: Matthew with JPA i am getting  __id was null. Either use #{#n1ql.selectEntity} or project __id Error, when i execute query in Couchbase console it works but with jpa program it does not.

Comment: I don't know enough about JPA to help you. I'd suggest posting another question here on in the Couchbase forums, or in the Couchbase Discord, with the JPA code

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT RAW count(1) FROM main_data)[0] AS count_data,
  (SELECT hosp_d.* FROM main_data AS hosp_d LIMIT 5) AS paged_data;
```

This is performance wise optimal.

```
SELECT RAW count(1) FROM main_data
```

Above query use collection stats for count because no WHERE clause and single count(1) expression

```
(SELECT hosp_d.* FROM main_data AS hosp_d LIMIT 5)
```

Above query only fetch 5 documents.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I have used is "pagination with total count", using the `OVER` window function.

Something like:

```
SELECT
   field1,
   field2,
   COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalCount
FROM <collection>
JOIN <whatever>
WHERE <predicates>
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```